# Chrome/Edge Devtools not loading source maps despite its presence

Tags: webpack, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, microsoft-edge, devtools

I am debugging a website where source maps are enabled but they are not visible in dev tools.

After checking multiple SOF threads and this https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/source-maps/#sourceurl_and_displayname I found the issue is probably because the `.js` files are missing the `//# sourceURL=source.coffee` comment in the end. So, I tried to right click and choose add source maps and pasted the URL of `.js` files and appended `.map` in the end. **That worked for me**, however this is a tedious task as there are around 30+ `.js` files. I was able to see `webpack://` being constucted after doing this.

Is there any hacky way to automate this? Or let dev tools know to that all source maps are just the same URLs with `.map` in the end? Or maybe some Chrome Extension that can do this for us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution myself after exploring. This can be done my creating a Chrome Extension on **version 2** for development.

Below is the code for Content Script.

```
function loadSynchronously(url: string) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, false);
    xhr.send();
    return xhr.responseText;
}

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function (details) {
        var javascriptCode = loadSynchronously(details.url);

        // modify the below rules as per your need
        javascriptCode += "\n//# sourceMappingURL=" + details.url + ".map";

        return {
            redirectUrl:
                "data:text/javascript," + encodeURIComponent(javascriptCode),
        };
    },
    {
        urls: ["https://www.example.com/*.js"],
    },
    ["blocking"]
);
```

Making sure to give `webRequest` and `webRequestBlocking` permission to your extension. I used this template https://github.com/abhijithvijayan/web-extension-starter. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you'll need to add `sourceURL` manually to give them different names. The idea of adding `sourceURL` is introduced because the Sources tool doesn't have a file name to display these files in the Navigator pane.

Comment: Hi! Due to some reasons I don't have permission to modify the code from server. Is it possible using some extension or middleware which can just read a `.js` file append the `sourceURL` automatically in the eof. All URLs are just `fileName.js.map`

Comment: Hi @RohanGupta. AFAIK, such kind of extension or third-party plugin is not available right now.